# How to covert String input into byte array?

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm trying to covert the string input in the serial to byte of array to write in a block in RFID card

```
String puta = "PUTANGINA";
byte blockcontent[16] = {puta};
```

I expect the output will be the string will be byte array.

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/tochararray/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getBytes()` this copies the string's characters to the supplied buffer.

Syntax:

- `string.getBytes(buf, len)`

Parameters:

- string: a variable of type String
- buf: the buffer to copy the characters into (byte [])
- len: the size of the buffer (unsigned int)

Returns

- None

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference.StringGetBytes

Comment: Copy/Paste from the documentation without a citation is not the best way to answer. An example would be much better.